# Cloud Load Testing in Visual Studio Online in Continous Testing - 401 error unauthorized issue

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Am trying to keep load test from VSO using the task "Load test using Azure IaaS VM’s task/Cloud Load testing" for an application hosted in an IaaS Environment.

Build Template used: .NET template

1. Created Build Definition
2. Builded the solution - Passed
3. Added task "Load test using Azure IaaS VM’s task/Cloud Load testing" in the build definition . Provided all
   the necessary details for the task but when running facing issue

Option selected: Self Provisioning

For Test Controller: Set up a VM machine using Azure Dev Test Labs

For Test Agent: Set up a VM machine using Azure Dev Test Labs

Non Hosted Agent: For running the Build, tried to use Test Controller/a dedicated Agent but still facing the same issue.

Error Details:

System.Net.WebException -> Remote server returned 401 error unauthorized****

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the entire log? If you use "Automatically provisioned agents", how's the result? How did you install on-premises Cloud Load Test Agent? Did you follow this blog: http://blog.devmatter.com/installing-the-cloud-load-test-agent-on-premises/?

Comment: Thanks Cece for your response. Yes, we followed the same steps to create test agent. But still got the above issue.

Comment: Could you share the entire log? If you use "Automatically provisioned agents", how's the result?